# Floor function in BST, Is this the Implementation or am i missunderstanding its use?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am teaching myself some datastructures, and I am wondering if this is the correct implementation of the floor function in a BST? I'll cut to the chase...

```
def floor(self, key):
    if self.root == None:
        return False

    return self._floor(self.root, key)

def _floor(self, node, key):
    if key == node.key:
        return node

    if key < node.key:
        if node.left == None:
            return node

        return self._floor(node.left, key)

    if node.right == None:
        return node

    return self._floor(node.right, key)
```

Above is how I have implemented the function, which seems to work fine. However I have written some unit tests one of which are failing.

```
def test_floor_NoLeftSubTree_HighestElementLowerThanValueReturned(self):
    # Arrange
    self.tree.insert(100)
    self.tree.insert(102)
    self.tree.insert(101)
    self.tree.insert(110)
    self.tree.insert(115)
    self.tree.insert(120)
    self.tree.insert(130)

    # Act, Assert
    self.assertEqual(self.tree.floor(109).key, 102)
```

I just wanted to clarify that my understanding is correct. The above test is failing because it's returning 110, not 102. I think it should return 102. Any nudges in the right direction would be helpful thanks...

I'm learning from [this](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/) document.

**EDIT:**
This is how i think the tree should look.

```
                    100
                        102
                    101     110
                                115
                                    120
                                        130
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code reaches node `102` it decides to go to the right child, that is `110`. However the `110` node has no left child, and the routine returns the current node (`110`). You should rather return "None" in this case (as there is no *floor(109)* candidate here), then on the previous level return the current node (that is `102`): return `self._floor(node.right, key)` if it is not `None`, return `node` otherwise.